# Connect JSON data to SQL Server as External Table

Tags: json, sql-server

I have found webpage with statistics in JSon format

For example:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD
[statistic data](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD)

I would like quickly connect this data as a table or view in SQL Server. Is this possible?

Comment: If you think of a *virtual table* you can call like `SELECT * FROM AnExternalSourceOnTheWeb` I'm afraid there's no *easy going*. There are rather clumsy approaches to access a source on the web directly from SQL-Server, but I'd advise to read the JSON with a better suiting technology. JSON is supported not before v2016. So you might read **and interpret** the JSON somewhere else and deal with the pure data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a stored procedure such as `[sp_OAMethod][1]` to pull data from API.
And then parse received JSON using `OPENJSON`.
[This article would be helpful to you.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/JSON/141175/)

Comment: OpenJSON SQL is interesting, so this answer is correct one, but also not easy one and with many restrictions.

Comment: @justromagod keep in mind that `OpenJson` starts from SQL Server 2016.

Comment: I think Microsoft should by some ADO.NET to JSON companies who already made drivers. I just realised json is represent whole database, not just table. So I need connect Json page as EXTERNAL DATABASE

Comment: @justromagod maybe is it another question? Could you create another question with all your requirements?

Comment: sure, just need first do research on this, to be sure it is not duplicate